# QtWebkit synchronous loading

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

I'm using a QWebPage without a QWebView because I want to render the contents of an HTML file onto a QPixmap/QImage.

I want the loading of the page to be done synchronously, *not* asynchronously which is the default. The default way is to call `QWebFrame::setHtml()` or `QWebFrame::setContent()`, but this loads images asynchronously. What I want is some sort of blocking function call, something like `QWebFrame::waitUntilLoadFinished()` after which I could just call `render()` and be done with it.

I can't find a way to do this. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's interested, I implemented this using a special "PageRasterizer" class.

The class creates a QWebPage in the constructor and sets a bool loading flag to false. A `connect()` call connects the `loadFinished` signal to a member slot that merely sets the loading flag to true.

A special `RenderPage()` member function that returns an image does all the work: it accepts the HTML string and calls `setHtml()`. After that comes a `while` loop that waits on the flag; while the flag is false, `qApp->processEvents()` is called so signals get emitted and the flag setting slot is eventually called. When it is, the loop breaks and now you can render the page to a QImage (don't forget to set the flag back to false before returning).

If you're interested in the rendering process, look at [this Qt example](http://doc.troll.no/4.6/qwebpage.html#using-qwebpage-in-a-widget-less-environment) (the `Thumbnailer::render()` function).

For bonus points, you can make this class a functor.

Comment: I definitely recommend not using busy polling via a loop but proper synchronization like wait conditions.

Comment: Signals will not be emitted unless the Qt event loop is running. But the event loop processes events and then returns. My solution merely runs the Qt event processing until Webkit is done loading.
I'd like to see your code using QWaitConditions _when you don't have access to the Webkit threads_...

Comment: I said *recommend* and of course i assume that you are not using the main thread as the worker thread which means you simply don't have to poll events manually.

Comment: I hope you are no professional programmer, hotspinning is the worst thing you can do.
And a snippet of coed often helps a lot more than explaining difficult structure.
Your example does not require hotspinning either.

Comment: It's hardly hotspinning, I'm merely running the Qt event loop.

Comment: Lucas, do you by chance still have some example code for this solution? I'm running into a similar problem with QtWebkit. I load external webpages and it slows down the GUI until the pages are finished loading. I realize that this answer is over 2 years old, but it looks promising. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

If someone still needs it, this is how I got it working.

```
mWebPage->mainFrame()->setHtml("...");
QEventLoop loop;
connect(mWebPage,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),&loop,SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
/* your webpage has finished loading & is ready to use */
```

Comment: To be more safe you could add a single shot timer with a timeout to quit the event loop if something goes wrong: QTimer.singleShot(10000, loop.quit)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to do it the Qt way and do it async, it helps a *lot*.

In case you still want to do it in Sync, use [QEventLoop](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qeventloop.html) in a seperate [QThread](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qthread.html).

See my comment for detailed QThread usage information.
Note: do not forget to call moveToThread(); within the thread header, or all signals will go over the QApplication execution loop.

Comment: See now _that's_ useful information. I didn't know about QEventLoop. Now I can push it to a new thread and wait for that to finish.

Comment: For proper QThread usage see http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Answer (score 2):

That approach has the problem that you basically have to wait for an undetermined amount of time and if you're issuing the call from the main thread you're blocking event processing and thus signals like `loadFinished`.

While you *could* get around that by explictly pumping event, i don't see an inherent problem that could prevent you from issuing the page-load and just do the processing when `loadFinished` occured.
If you need secondary threads to wait for the page, you could always let those threads wait by using synchronisation mechanisms.

Comment: Waiting is not a problem, the resources are from disk and I control them. They're very small. But you've given me an idea with QFutureWatcher...

Comment: Also, I explicitly want to avoid waiting for a signal. I just want to load a small page from disk, render it to an image and return that image. That should be one function, not several + slot + waiting for the signal etc...

Comment: As Qt doesn't provide that itself, you have to wait for the signal somewhere - even if its just hidden by some code. I haven't tried Qts future watcher yet, but the example looks like it can do exactly what you want - waiting for signals.

Comment: But you need something that returns a QFuture, and nothing in QtWebkit does.

Comment: I might have looked wrong then - but then there are other synchronization mechanisms that you can use for a wrapper.